# 600 tables in DDBB

Tags: database, oracle

I'm a very young software architect. Now I'm working in a very large and I have to lead a group of developers to rewrite all the mortgage system of the bank.

I'm looking at database tables and I realize that there is no any data model, neither documentation. The worst part is that there are about 1000 tables in dev environment, and like 600 in production. I trust more the production environment, but anyway, what can I do? I mean, I can suicide me or something, but is there any good reverse engineering tool, so at least I could get the schema definition with the relations between tables and comments extracted from the fields? Can you advice me something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now I feel more relieved about my money...

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky and the database actually uses primary and foreign keys, you can get some excellent documentation with [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/), a nice command line tool written in Java.

**Update:** I've just remembered that [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/index.html) has a similar tool (create a connection, right click on its icon and choose "Generate DB Doc") though it doesn't draw graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is oracle. For mysql there is a pretty nice tool called [Mysql Workbench](http://www.mysql.de/products/workbench/).

Comment: of course, but I mean, at the end it's a sql script (schema).

Comment: yepp, i think it might be possible to tweak thw mysql workbench to work with oracle

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting with a tool called [TOAD](http://www.quest.com/toad/) - it has been some years since i used it but IIRC you could select the appropriate schema that you want to inspect and it will give you a tree view with all the tables and views and you can expand the table nodes to see the column details. No doubt the tool has moved on considerably since i last used it.

Comment: Yeah, Toad 10 has a very nice database documentation feature called "Code Road Map" that comes with all versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the comments like so

```
select * from dba_tab_comments 
 where owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
```

and

```
select * from dba_col_comments 
 where owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
```

As for reverse engeneering: if you're going to draw an ERD with 600+ tables, this is (probably) going to be too large anyway. I'd first try to find "clusters" of related tables and then use a specialized tool to draw these clusters.

Obviously, you want to make sure that the entire schema *has* foreign keys enforced. You might want to look at

```
select * from dba_constraints 
 where constraint_type = 'R' and 
       owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
```

to see if all foreign keys.

Comment: Table/column comments are great but I've only ever worked one place where they have been used. And you'd have to imagine if there is no data model....

Comment: well, actually, there are comments. Not on all tables, of course, but at least something is something.

Comment: I have no rights to see these tables. Of course I can ask for it, but it's not what I want to do.